# Laravel - Unable to Insert Record in DB

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am having trouble to insert record in DB, here is my code

```
$member = new User; 
$member->user_name = Input::get('user_name'); 
$member->email = Input::get('email'); 
$member->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password')); 
$member->name = Input::get('name'); 
$date = date('Y-m-d'); 
$member->renewal_date = $date; 
$member->user_type = MemberType::FreeMember; 
$member->status = MemberStatus::NewUser; 
$member->save();
```

It simply not working and redirecting back to the form without any message or errors.
Please help me out. Thanks,

Comment: Redirect back means there is validation error probably, show whole the controller method code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `MemberType::FreeMember;` and `MemberStatus::NewUser;` are doing. And your date should be generated by the database too.

Can you first try it with this columns:

```
$member = new User; 
$member->user_name = Input::get('user_name'); 
$member->email = Input::get('email'); 
$member->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password')); 
$member->name = Input::get('name'); 
$member->save();
```

Ones you got this working you can debug the rest! Of course the member variables should match the columns in your database.